# Draw cube if any key clicked opengl 3d

Tags: opengl

i need help with drawing cube by the keyboardup method , For example if i clicked 'a' then a cube must be displayed.
what i have reached so far

```
void KeyUp(unsigned char key, int x, int y) {
    if (key == 'a') {glutSolidCube(5);}
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

but nothing appear in the opengl.

want to let you know that when i put `glutSolidCube(5);` in the display method it works.

Answer (score 1):

Toggle a "display cube" Boolean in your keyboard callback (and keep the `glutPostRedisplay()`) and (selectively) draw the cube in your display callback.

Comment: If i want to add more than cube , so i must declare more booleans ?

Answer (score 1):

> but nothing appear in the opengl.

Because after drawing `glutSolidCube(5)` in keyboard method, you clear the viewport in the display method. Thus everything drawn is wiped out.

> when i put glutSolidCube(5); in the display method it works.

It is working there because you are probably drawing at the right location (i.e.) after clearing the viewport and before posting.

Declare a global boolean and set it true at key callback method.
Use the boolean to decide if you have to draw the cube or not in your display mathod.